# Android Telephony Stack and Dalvik process contexts

Tags: android, dalvik, android-context, telephony

I am in the process of understanding the telephony stack in Android, and I would like you to confirm or dismiss a conclusion that I made:

- **The entire internal java telephony stack, i.e. [ril](http://source.android.com/porting/telephony.html) (java side), com.android.internal.telephony.* classes and default Android phone app are running inside the same [dalvik virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29)?**

Reading the source it seems that the (very limited) exposed telephony API through [TelephonyManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html), [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html), [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html), and friends, performs [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to the phone app dalvik process using the [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) interfaces ITelephony, ISms, IPhoneStateListener, etc.

**Is this correctly understood, and can you elaborate on my understanding if possible? :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the telephony stack that exists in the framework is instantiated by the phone app.  The phone app is set up as a persistent process, so the system starts it early in boot and makes sure it stays running.

The phone app is at packages/apps/Phone.  Its manifest package name (and thus the name of the process it runs in) is com.android.phone.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually gained the same understanding by reading the source, however I never got around to writing an answer here. So thanks. :)